# Hibernate one to one mapping by annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying an application in Hibernate to implement hibernate one-to-one association by annotations. I am using two POJO classes and associate them with each other but on execution I facing this issue.

Code : I have 2 classes Student, Address. I need a bidirectional 1-1 mapping between both.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "STUDENT")
    public class Student {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
        private String firstName;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy="student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Address address;

        ----getters and setters---
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ADDRESS")
    public class Address {

        @Id
        @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
        @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign",parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="student"))
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "STREET")
        private String street;

        @Column(name = "CITY")
        private String city;

        @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
        private String country;

        @OneToOne
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        private Student student;

        ----getters and setters---
    }
```

Below is my sample main class

```
    public class MainClass1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Session  session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Student student = new Student("Sam","Disilva","Maths");
            Address address = new Address("10 Silver street","NYC","USA");
            student.setAddress(address);
            session.save(address);
            session.save(student);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            HibernateUtil.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Exception trace :

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.learn.main.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at com.learn.main.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at com.learn.main.MainClass1.main(MainClass1.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1127)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1283)
    at com.learn.main.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Please, add the code.

Comment: And add a problem statement too...

Comment: Added code to my question above

Comment: I am getting below exception :

Comment: @Unknown It is not a duplicate.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate you use? And, please, add `HibernateUtil`.

Comment: i am using 3.2.1.ga hibernate version. HibernateUtil code is mention below

Comment: public class HibernateUtil {
   private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
   private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
     return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
     System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
     throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
   }
   public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
   }
   public static void shutdown() {
    getSessionFactory().close();
   }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to change the `@OneToOne` mapping on the `Address` part.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_student")
    private Student student;

}
```